# Java BigDecimal's negative fraction to binary form

Tags: java, arrays, bigdecimal

I need advice how to properly convert negative fractional part to binary.
My custom data type with fixed point need be converted to `byte[]`.
So, currently I need to implement such conversion:

```
BigDecimal -> byte[] -> BigDecimal
```

As I understand, fraction follows the same `2's complement` form as an integer part, right?
How one can distinquish "plain -1" from negative fraction? 
Short generic case example would be very usefull.

How one will write -1.375 and -0.375 in binary ?

Comment: Why? Is it necessary? This looks like a XY Problem...

Comment: Yeap, it is necessary.

Comment: Let's assume that you really need to use a byte[] ... don't see the needs here (it is serialisable you know) but you probably could find your answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167697/how-to-convert-java-bigdecimal-to-normal-byte-array-not-2s-complement)

Comment: I am a bit unclear what you want -13.456 to -0.456 maybe to -456 E-3?

Comment: I just need to understand how to properly convert negative fraction to binary. Java, BigDecimal or whatever are not the case. I developing ABI, so binary form should be unbound from any implementation.

Comment: `unscaledValue().toByteArray()` and `scale()` are implementation independent, and so are their results. They produce well defined values. That can be used for an ABI.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can code as (updated):

Convert to byte[]

```
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(bos);
    BigDecimal d = BigDecimal.valueOf(-0.00390625);
    dos.writeInt(d.scale());
    dos.write(d.unscaledValue().toByteArray());
    dos.close(); // flush
    byte[] array = bos.toByteArray();
```

Convert from byte[]

```
    ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(array);
    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(bis);
    int sc = dis.readInt(); //grab 4 bytes
    BigInteger unscaledVal = new BigInteger(Arrays.copyOfRange(array, 4, array.length));
    System.out.println(new BigDecimal(unscaledVal, sc));
```

Note: probably you would like to save `BigDecimal` array length.

Comment: It actualy gives me wrong result:
for -0.00390625 (least negative for 8 bit fraction) convertion returns 0.16386591

Just can't find clear algorithm how to handle negative fractions. I can feel it is exists)

Comment: See my update. We need also `scale` to correctly recover `BigDecimal`

Comment: because unscaledValue just do `bd.value * 10 ^ bd.scale`.

Comment: Thanks for trying, but it's not what I am actualy looking for. Am developing ABI, so binary form of my datatype should be unbound from any technology.

Comment: There is no technology - I have to put into byte buffer to components which are part of `BigDecimal`: the scale and the unscaled value.